# Crash of Intel HD Graphics 520

Tags: laptop, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

My ASUS UX303U laptop has 2 graphics processing units; Intel HD Graphics 520 and Nvidia 940M. The Intel GPU freezes often when playing video, and will not unfreeze except by a power off, but I need HDMI connected to Intel. NVIDIA runs OK except it  has no HDMI.

Both have their latest drivers; Windows 10x64 is updated to the latest updates. The ASUS support assistant is installed but doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling both Intel and NVIDIA driver and, after fresh reboot, reinstalling the drivers?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  Edit your question to include this vital information.  Additional, what version of the Intel drivers do you have installed?  Provide specifics, and URLs, to the exact versions of the drivers you are using.

Comment: And additionally, in laptops with hybrid graphics, the video outputs are the same. If you have HDMI it should work with whatever card/profile used at the moment. That it doesn't with Nvidia according to your description, suggests there's a problem with the drivers or something else. However, I'm not suggesting the use of Nvidia for multimedia contents, the Intel graphics is more than enough and saves energy.

Comment: Asus https://www.asus.com/us/search/results.aspx?SearchKey=UX303 has no UX303U; is your latop the UX303UB https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UB/HelpDesk_Manual/ or some other model? Please click [edit] and update your question with that information.

Comment: Model ASUS UX303U written on back side of laptop, Windows 10 x 64 with latest updates. Both drivers were uninstalled and installed again after reboot. Nvidia alone working as required so that issue concern only Intel video card. Intel driver version 22.20.16.4771 dated 13.08.2017 been updated by system. HDMI port installed on Intel card so when Intel switched off there is no signal in HDMI port

Comment: ASUS assistant marked model as UX303UB. Still need good advice to recover Intel HD Graphics 520